# How to Properly Resolve M:M Relationships in an Entity Relationship Model

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

To demonstrate my question, I will create a simple relationship between two entities: Person and Cooperation. A Person must work for one or more Cooperations while a cooperation may not have any associated persons working in it.

Diagram of this relationship: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E4AF.jpg

When resolving this M:M relationship by creating an intersecting entity, how would we properly implement this optionality? Would the following be correct:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7M14.jpg

If this solution is not correct, please specify how to properly resolve this M:M relationship. Specifically, I am wondering if how I have set the optionality of the relationships are correct when adding an associative table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using oracle data modeler, when you click at "Engineer to Relational Model" and then "Engineer" oracle will do the job for u

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFrLb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
persons table
-------------
id
first_name
last_name
...


cooperations table
------------------
id
name
...


cooperation_persons table
-------------------------
cooperation_id
person_id
```